Proving the Liouville Numbers are uncountable
The definition I'm given for the Liouville numbers is just that $x$ is Liouville if for every $N > 0$ there exists integers $p,q \geq 2$ such that
$$\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{q^N}.$$
I don't have too many high powered theorems to work with, except for things like the equivalence between Zorn, AoC and Well Ordering, Schroeder-Bernstein and a few other "bread and butter" set theory results. Is there a way to do this with any of those tools, or an explicit bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ (or some other set whose uncountability is easily verified) and the Liouvilles, or something else that uses some of those bread and butter set theory results?
Thanks.

Do you know an explicit Liouville Number?

I don't know of any, no. I just know that the Liouvilles are a subset of the transcendentals.

You can prove that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{a_n}{10^{n!}}$ where $a_n \in {1,2,...,9}$ is a Liouville number, well, that is an uncountable set of numbers.

Any number of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n\over 3^{n!}}$$ where $a_n\in \{1,2\}$ is a Liouville number. The cardinality of the set of such numbers  is continuum.

Consider the continued fraction expansion of an irrational number $x$: $$x =[a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots] = a_0 + \cfrac1{a_1 + \cfrac1{a_2 + \cfrac1{a_3 + \dots}}}$$ If we truncate the continued fraction of $x$ to the rational number $p_n/q_n = [a_0; a_1, \dots, a_n]$, the error in the approximation $|x - p_n/q_n|$ decreases as $a_{n+1}$ increases. By choosing $a_{n+1}$ to be large enough, the error can be made arbitrarily small.
(Not much theory of continued fractions is necessary to see this; all we need to know is that the function $[a_0; a_1, \dots, a_n + z]$ is a rational function of $z$ that approaches $p_n/q_n$ as $z \to 0$, and that $x = [a_0; a_1, \dots, a_n + z]$ where $z = [0; a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \dots]$.)
We can construct uncountably many Liouville numbers by a continued fraction approximation that begins with, say, $a_0 = 1$, and continues as follows:

Choose the odd terms by letting $a_{2k+1}$ be the least positive integer such that $|x - p_{2k}/q_{2k}| < (1/q_{2k})^k$.
Choose the even terms to be arbitrary positive integers.

